# jquery check if input value has changed dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have to implement following issue. I have input and i need to show warning message if its value has changed. But for some reasons alert shows few times, can't figure out why. Here was the first question.

```
$("#input").bind("propertychange change paste input", function(){
    alert("Value has been changed");
});
```

**The second question:**

How can i check if input's value has changed dynamically. For example if i click on some element then value changes.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#input").val("test");
})
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/1700/) i've created.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

There is no event raised when an inputs value is changed dynamically. Your best option is to manually raise an event upon changing the value:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#input").val("test").trigger('change');
})
```

Comment: thank you, what about first question?Alert windows shows few times: first - when i'm typing something, second - when i unfocused input

Comment: It shows once for each event fired. You have attached it to multiple events. The `change` event fires when the element is unfocussed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event for that instead you have to use `trigger the change event`

```
 $("a").click(function(){
    $("#input").val("test");
    $("#input").trigger("change");
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/W4Km8/1701/)

Comment: thank you, what about first question?Alert windows shows few times: first - when i'm typing something, second - when i unfocused input

Answer (score 0):

When value change value dynamically then you should bind event with element, see below sample

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#input").val("test").change();
})
```